# Reducing nested for loop to single loop in R

Tags: r, performance, loops

This nested for loop can take quite some time to run depending on inputs to specs, perms and K. 'pop' is just an array to store all values. Perms is a large value, say 10,000.

```
K <- 1 

N <- 100 

Hstar <- 10 

perms <- 10000 

specs <- 1:N 

pop <- array(dim = c(c(perms, N), K))

haps <- as.character(1:Hstar)

probs <- rep(1/Hstar, Hstar) 

for(j in 1:perms){
    for(i in 1:K){ 
        if(i == 1){
            pop[j, specs, i] <- sample(haps, size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs)
    }
        else{
            pop[j ,, 1] <- sample(haps[s1], size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs[s1])
            pop[j ,, 2] <- sample(haps[s2], size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs[s2])

        }
    }
}

HAC.mat <- array(dim = c(c(perms, N), K))

for(k in specs){
    for(j in 1:perms){
        for(i in 1:K){ 
            ind.index <- sample(specs, size = k, replace = FALSE) 
            hap.plot <- pop[sample(1:nrow(pop), size = 1, replace = TRUE), ind.index, sample(1:K, size = 1, replace = TRUE)] 
            HAC.mat[j, k, i] <- length(unique(hap.plot))  
       }
   }
}


means <- apply(HAC.mat, MARGIN = 2, mean)
lower <- apply(HAC.mat, MARGIN = 2, function(x) quantile(x, 0.025))
upper <- apply(HAC.mat, MARGIN = 2, function(x) quantile(x, 0.975))

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))

plot(specs, means, type = "n", xlab = "Specimens sampled", ylab = "Unique haplotypes", ylim = c(1, Hstar))
polygon(x = c(specs, rev(specs)), y = c(lower, rev(upper)), col = "gray")
lines(specs, means, lwd = 2)
HAC.bar <- barplot(N*probs, xlab = "Unique haplotypes", ylab = "Specimens sampled", names.arg = 1:Hstar)
```

To make the loop run faster, I am thinking to condense the above loop into a single loop and having a single index (i) run from 1:(specs*perms) and using modular arithmetic with floor and ceiling functions to get the job done. I am not quite certain how best to implement this.

Comment: Can you describe in words what your loop is doing? Have you identified the bottleneck (probably the `unique` bit)? It's a bit hard to follow when you use `k` to index `specs` but `i` to index `K`...

Comment: AM I the only one getting only NA in `HAC.mat`?

Comment: I have never gotten NA in HAC.mat before

Comment: I haven't shown all code, but results from the loops are used to plot some curves... essentially the code randomly samples character labels from haps and plots this against N

Comment: Maybe a naive question: does a single for loop run faster than a nested for loop?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure if there is a way to eliviate the overhead since you are still looking to do `length(K) * length(perms)` replicates of the `sample()` function.  Using `replicate()`, we can run `sample()` multiple times and bring it down to one for-loop, but the overhead of all these operations is still there.

Comment: Maybe a naive question but have you tried with `apply()` on a 3D array ?

Comment: @Toshiro No I have not tried apply(). I think for loops are unfortunately unavoidable here... though most (all?) programmers advise to get rid of them whenever possible,

Comment: @dvantwisk Interesting... I've thought of replicate() but believe that you may be correct, since each line within the inner-most loop takes a finite amount of time to run... My implementation may be as good as it gets! Thanks for the effort... It is always good to have a second opinion!

Comment: ([r]+[performance]+[loops] == [rcpp]) is `TRUE`.

Comment: @CPak Don't think so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use RcppArmadillo.
But first, I need to change 2 things to your code:

- It is easier (and faster) to work with `pop` as an array of integers rather than characters. It is easy to make a correspondence table using `unique` and `match`.
- I need to permute the first two dimensions of `pop` so that the accesses are more contiguous.

New code to generate `pop`:

```
K <- 1 
N <- 100 
Hstar <- 10 
perms <- 10000
specs <- 1:N 
pop <- array(dim = c(N, perms, K))
haps <- 1:Hstar
probs <- rep(1/Hstar, Hstar) 

for(j in 1:perms){
  for(i in 1:K){ 
    if(i == 1){
      pop[, j, i] <- sample(haps, size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs)
    }
    else{
      pop[, j, 1] <- sample(haps[s1], size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs[s1])
      pop[, j, 2] <- sample(haps[s2], size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs[s2])
    }
  }
}
```

RcppArmadillo code to generate `HAC.mat`:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#define ARMA_DONT_PRINT_OPENMP_WARNING
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>
#include <set>
using namespace Rcpp;


int sample_one(int n) {
  return n * unif_rand();
} 

int sample_n_distinct(const IntegerVector& x, 
                      int k,
                      const int * pop_ptr) {

  IntegerVector ind_index = RcppArmadillo::sample(x, k, false); 
  std::set<int> distinct_container;

  for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    distinct_container.insert(pop_ptr[ind_index[i]]);
  }

  return distinct_container.size();
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::Cube<int> fillCube(const arma::Cube<int>& pop,
                         const IntegerVector& specs,
                         int perms,
                         int K) {

  int N = specs.size();
  arma::Cube<int> res(perms, N, K);

  IntegerVector specs_C = specs - 1;
  const int * pop_ptr;
  int i, j, k;

  for (i = 0; i < K; i++) {
    for (k = 0; k < N; k++) {
      for (j = 0; j < perms; j++) {
        pop_ptr = &(pop(0, sample_one(perms), sample_one(K)));
        res(j, k, i) = sample_n_distinct(specs_C, k + 1, pop_ptr);
      }
    }
  }

  return res;
}
```

In R:

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp('cube-sample.cpp')
HAC.mat <- fillCube(pop, specs, perms, K)
```

This is 10 times as fast as your version on my computer.

Comment: I will test this out! Thanks! I will let you know if any issues arise.